# Can multiple dll reference to common config file outside the DLL ie DLL.config file

Tags: c#-4.0

I have Two DLL let it be abc.dll and xyz.dll i created two config file for them as the project acquirement abc.dll.config and zyz.dll.config.
both the file contain same information or the physical file path can i able to create common config file for both of them let it be common.dll.config that can be reference inside both the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use App.config (Windows Application) or web.config (Web Service) for both DLLs. You can combine settings needed for both DLLs in App.config or web.config file. Separate config files for DLLs are not needed.

Comment: Ok but I do not want to depend on the consumer ie app.config (windows application) who will consume my dll. I want my both DLL with the common config file for them separately ie Common.DLL.Config file

Comment: then using following code i can able to access them inside the DLL.var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("foo.dll");
config.ConnectionStrings. [etc]

Comment: Why do you intend to keep config file separate and not merge the settings in the app.config file? Keeping a separate config file will actually add overhead of managing a new config file. One way I am aware of is to define a custom configuration section. The custom configuration section can be declared in separate config file with all the settings. The app.config file will just need to declare the existence of custom configuration section.